# JBoss 7 HTTPS Connection works when run manually but runs at 8080 as Linux service

Tags: linux, sockets, service, jboss

Currently I am using JBoss 7.1.0 and have modified the **standalone.xml** file so that HTTPS connection is available via socket-binding under **socket-binding-group**.

```
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8089"/>
```

I added connector under the **subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1** related tag similar to this

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="somepassword" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
</connector>
```

When I run the server through this command: ./standalone.sh, the webapp is loaded and I can access it at `https://someaddress:8089/myapp`

I then moved forward to create a linux service for managing jboss. The steps are shown here: [Run JBoss as a Linux Service](https://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/getstarted/2.4.2.3+Run+JBoss+as+a+Linux+Service)

I can start and stop the service but the webapp is now available at 8080 port over http (`http://someaddress:8080/myapp`). If I try to access over `https://someaddress:8089/myapp` I get "This webpage is not available" in browser.

I am not sure what is wrong, but it seems like when I start it as service it runs on default port.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What messages you have in /var/log/jboss-as/console.log?

Comment: Thank you for putting it straight. I should have checked the log file but I assumed no error will be shown as it worked manually. However on checking log I found the problem and solution. I pointed the SSL file via relative path which is okay for running through bin folder, but not okay when run from service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem area at last. Thanks to Federico for asking for output of log file. The problem was with the path of SSL file in standalone.xml. Here is the error:

```
<ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="mypassword" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
```

When run manually the relative path works well, as it backtracks bin folder and finds the standalone directory. But when started as a service it doesn't work. Solution was to set it as below:

```
<ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="mypassword" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
```